# Error Error: Compile Error: Unexpected token 'lacc'. at line 5 column 4

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

```
public with sharing class Myfirstvfclass {

    public list<Account> lacc { get; set; }
    public Myfirstvfclass(){
        lacc=new list<Account> ([select id from Account]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor syntax is incorrect.

We write constructor as a method() with no return type.

```
public with sharing class Myfirstvfclass {

    public list<Account> lacc { get; set; }
    public Myfirstvfclass() {
        lacc=new list<Account> ([select id from Account]);
    }
}
```

You can read more about Constructors in apex here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_constructors.htm

Answer (score 3):

The signature for constructor is incorrect, you are missing the parenthesis for constructor.

Below line should be replaced

```
public Myfirstvfclass // Incorrect without parenthesis
```

with

```
public Myfirstvfclass() //correct way of defining the constructor
```

Your class should be

```
public with sharing class Myfirstvfclass {

    public list<Account> lacc { get; set; }
    public Myfirstvfclass(){
        lacc=new list<Account> ([select id from Account]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your constructor could be done in this way:

```
public with sharing class Myfirstvfclass {

    public list<Account> lacc { get; set; }
    public Myfirstvfclass() {
        lacc=new list<Account> ([select id from Account]);
    }
}
```

Comment: should not matter right? intance variable called from instance context?

Comment: I am wrong, I will correct it

Comment: You've changed the constructor to a method - a different thing.

Comment: yup. I could delete, as your answer is better then mine, but I believe it is not recommended to delete